# What does "scalar rate of one per clock" mean?

Tags: hardware, cpu

I read the following sentence from Intel Manual. Since I am nota native English speaker, I am not quite sure what "***scalar rate of one per clock***" means. Could anyone explains it to me?  Thanks.

> An 8-KByte on-chip first-level cache that increased the percent of
>   instructions 
>       that could execute at the scalar rate of one per clock

Answer (score 0):

In my words: **scalar** is the "weight" or "measure unit" of a function or property, in your case a clock unit.
So the manual reads like this: **the L1 cache on the CPU increased the percent of instructions with one instruction per one CPU clock unit.**

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by "**the percent of instructions with one instruction**"?

Comment: Yeah, I see it may be kind of confusing as well. Put in another way - 'increased the total amount of instructions with 1 per clock cycle'.